# Trying to create a Git repository using Gitlab throws an error

Tags: gitlab

```
$ git add remote origin https://gitlab.com/ramaaria/SymfonyProject.git
fatal: pathspec 'remote' did not match any files
```

Comment: It's `git remote add`, not `git add remote`.

Comment: Can be closed under: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._.

Answer (score 0):

There you have https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

In your case it would be

```
$ git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/ramaaria/SymfonyProject.git
```

Comment: Now I get $ git clone https://gitlab.com/ramaaria/SymfonyProject.git
Cloning into 'SymfonyProject'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/ramaaria/SymfonyProject.git/' not found